# Add something to another template block

Tags: django

Django 3.0.6

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}

{% include 'general/header.html' %}
<body>
<div class="content">
{% block content %}
    {% add_to_script jquery %}
{% endblock content %}
</div>

{% include 'general/footer.html' %}
```

**footer.html**

```
{% block scripts %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

**Problem**

Could you tell me whether it is possible to write {% add_to_script jquery %} that adds
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to scripts block?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that allow you to do that:
https://github.com/divio/django-sekizai

Example Template:

```
{% load sekizai_tags %}

<html>
<head>
    {% render_block "css" %}
</head>
<body>

... Your content comes here.
... Maybe you want to throw in some css:

{% addtoblock "css" %}
    <link href="/media/css/stylesheet.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
{% endaddtoblock %}

... Some more content here.

{% addtoblock "js" %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Hello django-sekizai");
    </script>
{% endaddtoblock %}

... content of js will be rendered here
{% render_block "js" %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't catch your idea. I wrote how I want to use block 'content'. Namely I write {% add_to_script jquery %} there. Nothing else. And I can't touch body that freely as you showed. There are two blocks: content and scripts. But I can touch only block content and only with one string: apply the above mentioned custom tag. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

1) try doing something like this inside `base.html` create file `scripts.html` which contains all the scripts file

```
{% include "scripts.html" %}

{% block extra_scripts %}
{% endblock extra_scripts %}
```

2) Whenever in other html templates you need to write scripts just write inside

`{% block extra_scripts %}`

3) Inside `scripts.html` put all your scripts value

```
{% load static %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/mdb.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- Initializations -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Animations initialization
  new WOW().init();

</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can't catch your idea. I wrote how I want to use block 'content'. Namely I write {% add_to_script jquery %} there. Nothing else. And I can't touch body freely. There are two blocks: content and scripts. But I can touch only block content and only with one string: apply the above mentioned custom tag. Can you help me?

Comment: I will try and let you know.